# what does "hold fat cats' paws to the fire" mean?

Tags: idioms, reading

[image]

the fourth line :

1. gravity-defying: I think i can figure what it means - their pay is so high - but I don't get it that the way the two words combine. I mean, I can't see these two words' relation.

the seventh line

1. hold fat cat's paws to the fire ... what?? is it a metaphor or sth? why they need to hold a fat cat, and why they have to hold their caws to the fire.. cruel...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_cat_(term)

Comment: @Michael_B  LOL, now i know, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fat cat" is an idiom for a wealthy person [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fat_cat):

> informal, derogatory
>
> A wealthy and powerful person, especially a
>   business person or politician.

To "hold someone's feet to the fire" means to apply persuasive pressure [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/foot):

> Put pressure on a person or organization in order to obtain a desired
>   result.

"Gravity-defying" is a common idiom meaning, well, to defy gravity.  Imagine a tightrope walker, eg.  Apt to fall at any moment.

Comment: thank you! that's clear! I'll remember tese two funny idiom!

Answer (score 0):

So the phrase is a mix of two well-known phrases.

1. **Fat cat** means an excessively rich person, usually one with undue political influence because of their wealth.
2. **Hold their feet to the fire** means to hold someone accountable when they would rather not be especially by applying political or popular pressure.

Combining these two leaves us with "Hold the fat cats' paws to the fire" - paws rather than feet because they are cats. So it means to hold rich political influencers accountable.

Comment: thank you ! i understand . that's a funny expression, i'll keep it in mind :)